# HorizontalScrollView swipe/fling guesture listener

Tags: java, android, gesture, horizontalscrollview

I know this is a common question , but I am completely messed with those different examples and tutorials available on the web.

I have a horizontalScrollView where I add some view dynamically , and I want to set a guestureListener for swiping through the Views . Each view's with is equal to the width of the screen.

Comment: Wouldn't a viewpager work for you? I haven't done a horizontalScrollView before but viewpagers are simple to create and use. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Can I use the view pager only for a part of the screen , not for the entire display ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the View Pager instead of the horizontalScrollView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

To keep the View pager at half the screen use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.5">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pagerPromo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicatorPromo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

This View Pager has a circle indicator at the bottom but you can remove that if you like. Just play around with the weights and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I will try it now . But will it work for API 8 ?

Comment: OK , I am trying it now . Thanks a lot